# NSfetchedResultsControllerDelegate crashed tableview

Tags: iphone, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**Hello everyone,
I'm using the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to update my tableview.
For example,**

**//Now tableview doesn't have any record.**

2009-11-15 12:25:48.328 XXX[36890:207] 0 //num sections before update
**//call tableview begin update**

2009-11-15 12:25:54.277 XXX[36890:207] insert 0 //insert new section
**//begin to insert data**

2009-11-15 12:25:54.278 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:31 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.278 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:30 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.278 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:45 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.279 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:62 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.279 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:12 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.280 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:54 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.280 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:2 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.280 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:14 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.281 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:63 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.281 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:27 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.281 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:5 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.282 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:7 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.282 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:44 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.283 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:51 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.283 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:9 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.283 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:29 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.284 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:64 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.284 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:22 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.284 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:25 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.285 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:57 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.285 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:50 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.286 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:13 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.286 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:8 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.287 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:61 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.287 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:15 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.287 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:53 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.288 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:37 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.288 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:34 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.288 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:52 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.289 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:58 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.289 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:4 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.290 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:41 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.290 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:49 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.290 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:39 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.291 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:26 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.291 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:20 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.291 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:1 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.292 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:21 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.292 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:65 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.293 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:38 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.293 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:59 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.293 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:47 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.294 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:28 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.294 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:3 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.295 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:55 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.295 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:23 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.295 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:56 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.296 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:40 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.296 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:16 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.296 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:6 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.297 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:60 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.297 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:17 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.298 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:11 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.298 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:33 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.298 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:19 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.299 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:46 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.299 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:36 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.299 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:42 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.300 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:18 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.300 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:48 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.301 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:43 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.301 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:0 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.301 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:10 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.302 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:32 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.302 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:35 section:0
2009-11-15 12:25:54.302 XXX[36890:207] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: row:24 section:0

**//finish update
//tableview crashed**

2009-11-15 12:25:54.303 XXX[36890:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (65) beyond bounds (1)'
2009-11-15 12:25:54.303 XXX[36890:207] Stack: (
    32556123,
    2434330441,
    32640059,
    32639898,
    2149577,
    1745447,
    ..
)

**My tableview crashed. Also, I don't call reloadData in my code.

Bud if I reload data after I finish update, and ignore all update events from FetchResultsControllerDelegate, everything works fine. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, Please read https://devforums.apple.com/message/118418#118418

Answer (score 0):

okay, so when nsfetchedresultscontroller want to insert multiple sections, it will send call both insert new sections and insert new rows in that new sections to its delegate; however, tableview only want the insert new sections. To solve this, we need to create a set which has all the new sections. When we insert new row, you can tell whether we should insert or now.